# Simple reference problems for time harmonic Maxwell equations

Tags: finite-element, electromagnetism

For Navier-Stokes problems we can often choose a relatively simple verification problem such as the lid driven cavity, flow over a cylinder, or flow over a backward facing step to verify our implementation.

What are the typical reference problems for the time harmonic Maxwell equations?

Edit: With a focus on finite element solutions in 3D and also possibly 2D if more common

Comment: Are you looking for bounded our unbounded domains?

Comment: I think probably more unbounded/scattering problems but either common problems would be good

Answer (score 3):

That depends a lot on the specific numerical method in use, 2D/3D, and application.

Common reference problems are likely to have an analytical solution or be verifiable qualitatively by some fundamental principles.

I would bring up the common examples I use personally from each category:

1. Wave scattering from a perfect electric conductor (PEC)/dielectric/layered-coated sphere. This problem has an [analytical solution (via Mie series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering) and can test multiple numerical aspects of the solver. Usually, a dipole or a planewave excitations are used.
2. [Testing reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(electromagnetism)) (where it is applicable): doing two simulations interchanging the resultant sources and observed fields.

I also use application-specific benchmarks for power, microwave, antenna, electromagnetic compatibility (EMC).

Also, it is important to mention the [*method of manufactured solutions* (MMS)](http://infoserve.sandia.gov/sand_doc/2000/001444.pdf) with some relevant discussions [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/14773/20688) and [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/29489/20688).

Comment: Thanks I've edited to specify I'm looking for common reference problems with regards to finite element in 3D. I did not have enough reputation to add a MMS tag and did not find one to add on to my question when I asked it

Comment: I would highlight more the MMS for verification purposes.